# How to optimize view performance in SQL Server 2012 by indexing

Tags: sql-server

I have a view like that:

```
create view dbo.VEmployeeSalesOrders
as 
   select 
       employees.employeeID, Products.productID,
       Sum(Price * Quantity) as Total,
       salesDate,
       COUNT_BIG() as [RecordCount]
   from 
       dbo.Employees
   inner join 
       dbo.sales on employees.employeeID = sales.employeeID
   inner join 
       dbo.products on sales.productID = products.ProductID
   group by 
       Employees.employeeID, products.ProductID, salesDate
```

When I `select * from dbo.VEmployeeSalesOrders` it takes 97% of the execution plan. It needs it to be faster.

And when I try to create an index, an exception fires with the following message:

> select list doesn't include a proper use on count_Big()

Why am getting this error?

Comment: If the 97% is the percentage at the query plan, please remember it is an estimate and can be a totally wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1-first you need to alter your view and make it contains COUNT_BIG() function because you used aggregate function in select statment,
AND THE REASON FOR USING THAT is that SQL Server needs to track the record where the record is ,number of records
like this

```
create view dbo.VEmployeeSalesOrders
 as 
   select employees.employeeID,Products.productID,Sum(Price*Quantity) 
    as Total,salesDate,COUNT_BIG(*) as [RecordCount]
    from dbo.Employees
         inner join dbo.sales on employees.employeeID=sales.employeeID
         inner join dbo.products on sales.productID-products.ProductID
group by Employees.employeeID,products.ProductID,salesDate
```

2- then you need to create index like that

```
 Create Unique Clustered Index Cidx_IndexName 
    on dbo.VEmployeeSalesOrders(employedID,ProductID,SalesDate)
```

Hope It Works

Comment: On top of that, you have to add hint `WITH (NOEXPAND)` when you query indexed view. `SELECT * FROM dbo.VEmployeeSalesOrders WITH (NOEXPAND)` for example.

Comment: @EvaldasBuinauskas, just want to add that the `WITH (NOEXPAND)` hint is not needed in SQL Server Enterprise and Developer editions.  The optimizer in those editions will consider indexes on views automatically, even when selecting directly from the underlying tables.

Comment: There Is No Need For Using With(NOEXPAND) as indexes will be put in consideration for views automatically

Comment: @Anas Saad Thanks It Works and in execution plan it takes 3% which i big different

Comment: @Darknight, be aware that applications that modify the underlying tables will get errors if the "magic 7" connection settings are not set properly as described in https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191432.aspx.

Comment: If you're on SQL Server 2008 or 2008R2 the NO EXPAND hint IS required.  Don't just dismiss it like that in general, because if you need your application to run on older SQL Server versions, you really MUST use it, and it's a best practice.